# Frattini Subgroup of Free Group

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

It is perhaps around 1950, proved by Higman and Neumann that the Frattini subgroup of a Free group is trivial.

I want to know, *now*, is there elementary proof of this?

If yes, please write short sketch or give directions for the proof; I would like to complete the proof.

Answer (score 1):

I will give the idea of proof,

Let $<a_1,...,a_n>=F$ where $F$ is a free group with generaters $n$ elements.

Assume that $\Phi(G)\neq 1.$

I will show the very basic case, If the word $a_1a_2\in \Phi(G)$, then notice that

$$<a_1,a_1a_2,a_3,a_4...,a_n>=F$$

As $a_1a_2$ is a nongenerotor,

$$<a_1,a_3,a_4..,a_n>=F$$

which is a contradiction.

Hence, the idea is that it does not contain any non- trivial words with this methods.